# Send uploaded image from a form to a second form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

How can I send an uploaded image from one form to a second form on submit? The code for the first form:

```
<form class="usp-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www.aeroe.com/gate/" data-validate="parsley" data-persist="garlic" novalidate>

<input name="usp-files" type="file" maxlength="255" data-required="false" placeholder="File(s)" class="usp-input usp-input-files select-file multiple" multiple="multiple" id="usp-multiple-files" />

<input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2">

</form>
```

Code for the second form. I need the file input on this second form to have the files from the previous form in it, which I will then submit at a later stage.

```
<form class="usp-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" http://www.aeroe.com/submit/" data-validate="parsley" data-persist="garlic" novalidate>

<input name="usp-files[]" type="file" maxlength="255" data-required="false" placeholder="File(s)" class="usp-input usp-input-files select-file multiple" multiple="multiple" id="usp-multiple-files" />
<input name="usp-file-limit" class="usp-file-limit" value="20" type="hidden" />
<input name="usp-file-count" class="usp-file-count" value="1" type="hidden" />

<div class="usp-preview"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2">

</form>
```

An unsuccessful solution I thought to include: Its been suggested that I use the following code in between my second form tags:

```
foreach ($_FILES["usp-files"] as $file) {
echo '<input name="usp-files[]" value="'.$file["usp-files"]["tmp_name"].'" type="hidden"  />';
}
```

along with this code to put in to the index file of http://www.aeroe.com/submit/ (I don't know where to find the index file):

```
foreach ($_POST["usp_files"] as $file) {
//get the location of the file
$fileslocation= tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $file);

//move the file to somewhere else
move_uploaded_file($file, $destination);
}
```

Comment: Simple answer: this is not possible for security reasons. You will never succeed to deliver a prefilled form to a browser referencing some file in the clients local system and expecting the browser to deliver this file to your server. That would be a _mile wide security catastrophy_, once you start thinking about it...

Comment: Is there no way that an uploaded file could be saved to my database, and then retrieved on another page instead? Or would that still have security issues?

Comment: That is something totally different. Of course you can save an uploaded file and later do whatever you want with that file and with the file name you received. You will _not_ however know what local path the file was selected from and you will not be able to somehow reaccess that file or location on the client side without the client side user explicitly triggering such action with a click.

Comment: @arkascha Okay, so a user on the front end could upload a file which could be saved within my site's database, which could then be retrieved later on another page? If this is possible, then that's a solution to my issue.

Comment: Sure, that is absolutely possible and common. Whether you want to save that file inside a database or some file system location depends on the situation. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @arkascha Great, thanks for your help!